# Why is error 410 a user error and not a server error?

Tags: rest, http, web, curl

Why is error 410 considered a user error (4xx) and not a redirect (3xx) or a server error (5xx)?
I request a payload from a server, and the server returns a link. I copy the link and the link gives 410? It isn't my fault to verify the link actually exists on their server. But at the same time, from the server's point of view the error originated from me, as I accessed something that doesn't exist, similar to 404 where I access something that was never there.

Can anyone help me understand the decision behind this?

[Code 410](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410)

> "410 Gone" client error response code indicates that access to the target resource is no longer available at the origin server and that this condition is likely to be permanent.
>
> If you don't know whether this condition is temporary or permanent, a 404 status code should be used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is error 410 a user error and not a server error?

It's not a "user" error, it's a [client error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-client-error-4xx); but yeah, that's a lousy label.  The labels reflect the [client-server architectural constraint](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_2), but it might be better to use labels that point more directly at the contents of the request, rather than the client (or the user).

In practice, it's a client error for the same reason that [404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-404-not-found) is a client error; it is specifically calling attention to the target resource of the HTTP request.

In the context of the web, it does make some (imperfect) sense - the client followed a broken link (which could be a consequence of the server's current representations, but might also come from following links in stale representations, following stale bookmarks, a spelling error in a representation provided by a different server, etc).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this and I appreciate the client/user correction as I was not aware

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question of fault, it just means that the request should not be considered to ever work in the future (it shouldn't be retried). Whereas a server error (like a 5xx error) could be retried periodically and should eventually work sometime in the future since the request itself is considered valid.

Comment: So it's safe to assume 4xx means "don't do this again" while 5xx means "try later" on all scenarios?

Comment: According to the [spec for 4xx errors](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5) and the [spec for 5xx errors](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6), in both cases, "the server SHOULD [say] whether it is a temporary or permanent condition."  So this answer isn't totally correct.

Comment: Although in practice, most 4xx shouldn't wouldn't be retried, whereas most 5xx errors could be.

Comment: Yeah, I guess my answer was an oversimplification. I can imagine temporary vs permanent 4xx errors, but I can't really imagine a 5xx error which the server would mark as permanent.